# Having issues with displaying my estimated cost

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Cost Estimate";
include 'header.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Services";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['service'])) {
    $selected_service = $_POST['service'];

    if ($selected_service == "Tile & Grout Cleaning") {
        $area = $_POST['area'];
        $cost = 0;

        // Fetch price from database
        $sql = "SELECT price FROM Services WHERE service_name = 'Tile & Grout Cleaning'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $price = $row["price"];

            $cost = $price * $area;

            echo "<h2>Cost Estimate for $selected_service</h2>";
            echo "<p>Area: $area square feet</p>";
            echo "<p>Estimated Cost: $$cost</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>No records found. Please select a service.</p>";
        }

    }

}

$conn->close();

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Estimate";
include 'header.php';
?>

<h2>Estimate</h2>
<center>

  <h2>Service Estimate Form</h2>
  <form action="estimate.php" method="post">
    <label for="service">Select a service:</label>
    <select class="service" name="service">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="Tile & Grout Cleaning">Tile & Grout Cleaning</option>
      <option value="Wooden Floor Polishing">Wooden Floor Polishing</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="estimate">
  </form>
  <br /><br />
  <?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $selected_service = $_POST['service'];

    if ($selected_service == "Tile & Grout Cleaning") {
      echo '<h2>Tile & Grout Cleaning</h2>';
      echo '<form action="cost.php" method="post">';

      echo '<label for="area">How large is the area to be cleaned (in square feet)?: </label>';
      echo '<input type="number" name="area" required><br><br>';
      echo '<input type="submit" value="Calculate Cost">';
      echo '</form>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>Please select a service.</p>';
    }
  } ?>

  <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

When I go to submit the details that are needed to estimate a total the cost page is blank. This has me stumped. I felt like I tried everything. Even went on chatgtp hoping for a solution but it told me to change the action estimate,php to cost,php but I need the action estimate,php to get the specifications of the service.

The output that should be shown is (random values added for output)

-Cost Estimate for Tile and Grout Cleaning

-Area: 100 square feet

-Estimated Cost: $90

I know I just posted everything but I'm new so I'm not sure how to properly use the features.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: That was wrong, variable variables are not coming into play here. You need to debug your execution to see what you have for each value. Also please add what your script output is. Sounds like it is `<p>Estimated Cost: $</p>` but please verify.

Answer (score 0):

Code adds a hidden input field to transfer the selected service from a form submission page to another page called cost.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Estimate";
include 'header.php';
?>

<h2>Estimate</h2>
    <center>
    <h2>Service Estimate Form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="estimate.php">
        <label for="service">Select a service:</label>
        <select class="service" name="service">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="Tile & Grout Cleaning">Tile & Grout Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Wooden Floor Polishing">Wooden Floor Polishing</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="estimate">
    </form>
<br />
<br />
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $selected_service = $_POST['service'];
    if ($selected_service == "Tile & Grout Cleaning") {
        echo '<h2>Tile & Grout Cleaning</h2>';
        echo '<form action="cost.php" method="post">';
        echo '<label for="area">How large is the area to be cleaned (in square feet)?: </label>';
        echo '<input type="number" name="area" required><br><br>';
        // Added hidden value to make sure service value is passed to cost.php in $_POST arguments
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="service" value="' . $selected_service . '">';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Calculate Cost">';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Please select a service.</p>';
    }
}

?>
    
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: `if ($_POST['serviceSubmitted']) {` does not check the existence of the superglobal array's element.

Comment: I have updated the code, I was trying something and I added in this code snippet.

Comment: There is no check that `$_POST['service']` was supplied in `$_POST`.

Comment: When an option's `value` attribute is identical to the option's text, the `value` attribute can be safely omitted.  `<option value="Tile & Grout Cleaning">Tile & Grout Cleaning</option>` can be slimmed down to `<option>Tile & Grout Cleaning</option>` without any side effects.

Comment: Like - if (isset($_POST['service'])) { // proceed further } ?

Comment: Yes, `isset()` is a good idea.  Also `for="area"` doesn't relate to any `id` on the page -- it does not relate to `name="area"`.  The input field needs to have `id="area"`.  It is important to always present best practices -- we don't know who will be learning from our answers.  If you don't want to refactor the whole script, then omit all of the irrelevant parts from your answer.  Don't let yourself be associated with suboptimal code.

Comment: I agree about the option value. The idea behind bringing the whole code is to let know that this is where hidden input is missing to pass the service value to cost.php

Comment: definitely, a lot of improvements is needed.